# What does "Continuity of response" mean in the book "Game Feel"

Tags: control, interface, realtime

In Steve Swink's book "Game Feel", he talks about 3 thresholds the computer must meet in order to maintain the illusion of real-time control.

> 1. The  impression  of  motion  (display  above  10    fps).
>    The  frames  displayed  on  the  screen must be above 10 per second to maintain the impression of motion.
>    The impression will be better and smoother at 20 or 30 frames per second.
> 2. Instantaneous response (input to display happens in 240  ms or less).
>    The computer’s  half  of  the  process  must  take  less  than  correction  cycle  for  the  player.  At  50    ms,  response  feels  instantaneous.
>    Above  100    ms,  the  lag  is  noticeable  but  ignorable. At 200  ms, the response feels sluggish.
> 3. Continuity of response
>    Cycle time for the computer’s half of the process stays at a consistent 100  ms or fewer.

Later in the book he restates the three items above, using slightly different language.

> 1. 10 frames per second. The images are displayed at a rate faster than one cycle of the  human  perceptual  processor,  which  will  be  50  to  200    ms.  Therefore,  images  displayed at a rate at or above a rate of 10 frames per second will appear fused into  motion,  and  20  frames  per  second  or  higher  is  necessary  for  a  smooth  motion. In the case of a game, this is not a series of linear frames played back in sequence but a series of states generated in response to input.
> 2. Response  time  of  100    ms  or  less.  The  game’s  response  to  input  happens  within  one perceptual cycle (50 to 200  ms) of the player’s action, fusing into a sense of causality and instantaneous response.
> 3. A continuous feedback loop. The game provides a continuous, unbroken flow of input and instant response, enabling ongoing correction cycles to occur.

I understand the first two thresholds, but I am struggling to understand "Continuity of response". His discussion on the topic does not make it clear for me.

What is "Continuity of response" and what does it feel like if there is no or poor continuity of response?

The "continuous feedback" phrase makes more sense to me, but still confused by what is meant by the 100ms in the Continuity of response description.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the book so can't answer your question (I'd guess at "consistency" of response, rather than continuity), but I will say those latencies are quite high by today's standards. Eg VR requires motion-to-photon times on the order of 20ms.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of conjecture; I haven't read the book, but did some digging on the author's [companion website  for the book](http://www.game-feel.com).

There I found links to some posts stating

> These articles were one of the reasons I started thinking about this
> stuff and wanted to write a book.

In particular, the post [Measuring Responsiveness in Video Games](https://cowboyprogramming.com/2008/05/30/measuring-responsiveness-in-video-games/) by Mick West caught my attention regarding processing consistency. In that post, Mick writes:

> Then what about the games where the lag varies? Harry Potter is 10-14
> which is bad enough, but Heavenly Sword is an astonishing 7-18. It
> takes 7/60ths to start an attack, but 18/60ths to start to turn around
> (See movie: mvi_4263w). Clearly something is wrong there. I would
> consider that a bug. It’s sad that the programmer made the effort that
> allowed for a 7/60th response time, but then someone else messed up
> down the line, making the turn take nearly a third of a second. Halo 3
> is another example, with the shooting and moving being 8, but the
> jumping being 10.

Combined with the definitions provided in the question, my read seems to match the suggestion in the comments that "continuity of response" refers to consistency & that a lack of consistency (which is to say a *variable* amount of lag introduced processing lag) further exaggerates a player's perception of a game's responsiveness.

Anecdotally, that feels reasonable. If a game has a consistent amount of processing lag, it's easier to learn how to lead & compensate. Whether intentional or not, it might even be internalized as part of the game. If the processing lag is inconsistent, the player can't effectively compensate & the gameplay feels worse.

Comment: I was unconvinced by your answer earlier as it did not jibe with the author's elaboration. But now having seen the tern defined slightly differently in a different part of the book (see edits above), I think you might be right.